# Does the Catholic Church teach that belief in the possibility of more than 3 persons in God is heresy?

Tags: catholicism, trinity

The Catholic Church teaches that not believing the Father, Jesus, and the Holy Spirit are all God (= 3 persons) is heresy. Does the Catholic Church have an official teaching on the belief that there are *at least* 3 persons who are God, but there may be more? Is this heresy?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I have updated the language from 'trinity' to 'who are God', as obviously, > 3 persons wouldn't be a trinity anymore - thanks for that catch.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Before the rise of Christianity, how many Jews thought God could be composed of 3 persons? It's conceivable a new version of Christianity could arise claiming God is composed of 4 (or more) persons.

Comment: Jews are fiercely monotheistic and that's why they are against Christians equating the human Jesus with God.  However, Christians have to account for Jesus and the Holy Spirit, who came to us in AD 30s.  In the past 2000 years there was never a debate as to the number, but on the **relationship** and the **nature** of each member of the Three as you can see from [alternate relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_heresies_in_the_Catholic_Church#Trinitarian/Christological_heresies) which necessitated the Nicaean definition. Who do you think can be a new member of the Godhead?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple "Who do you think can be a new member of the Godhead?" I don't know - it's a theoretical question approaching the idea of trinitarianism from another direction!

Comment: As to why there are exactly 3 Divine Persons, see St. Thomas Aquinas [_Summa Theologica_ I q. 30 a. 2 "Whether there are more than three persons in God?"](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP030.html#FPQ30A2THEP1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they be anathema who holdeth that idea:

> If anyone shall not confess that the nature or essence of the Father, of the Son, and of the Holy Ghost is one, as also the force and the power; [if anyone does not confess] a consubstantial Trinity, one Godhead to be worshipped in three subsistences or Persons: let him be anathema. For there is but one God even the Father of whom are all things, and one Lord Jesus Christ through whom are all things, and one Holy Spirit in whom are all things.
>
> [Second Council of Constanstinople - 553 A.D.](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/3812.htm)

So, the number is three, not more or less.